# Output image src with SimpleXML hidden characters

Tags: php, xml, decode

I'm using [SimpleXML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SimpleXML) to read nodes, and I echo out the image file name. Using foreach, I print them out:

```
assets/project_Guide2Big1.jpg
assets/​project_Guide2Big2.jpg
assets/​project_Guide2Big3.jpg
assets/​project_Guide2Big4.jpg
assets/​project_Guide2Big5.jpg
```

I inserted these values into my img tags, but the images don't appear except for the first one.

I copy "assets/project_Guide2Big1.jpg" into the browser. I see the image, but when I copy "assets/project_Guide2Big2.jpg", the address changes to this
asset/%E2%80%8BprojectGuide2Big2.jpg.

It looks like some urlencoding(?). I tried to decode, but my images still aren't working. This is so wierd.

Were does the `%E2%80%8B` come from?

Comment: It seems there is some extra hidden characters after slash. Check your xml file for this.

Comment: but why would it effect only the 2,3,4 and 5. The 1st one reads clean. And why doesn't it show in view source. It's so baffling.

Comment: Maybe first one doesn't have any extra chars!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks suspiciously like a UTF-8 character sequence representing some Unicode character which you didn't expect to be there.

Using [this online converter](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/), we can see that the sequence of UTF-8 bytes E2 80 8B represent the Unicode codepoint U+200B, which is a "Zero Width Space".

So somehow, your source XML includes an invisible character after the slash. When echoed to the screen, it is completely invisible - even when viewing source, since the source is still just text. But when you try to load the URL, that character is outside the valid range for URLs, so gets automatically encoded by the browser.

You might be wondering what the point of a zero-width space is, but consider automatic word-wrap functions - they may look for a space to break on, but a URL contains no spaces. So inserting a zero-width space makes the text *look* the same, but allows it to wrap at that specific point. Another character useful for this is the "soft hyphen", which has the beautifully apt entity name of `&shy;` - as a friend of mine put it, "the soft hyphen is shy, and may not appear". :)

Comment: Yea, i'm just realizing now, when i view source and inspect the invalid image it gives me the path with %E2%80%8B, there must be some php which strips ann encoding, i will google search for it.

Comment: It's not about how it is encoded, there is a character in the string which you need to remove. The encoding is just making it more obvious - even invisible, it would be the wrong URL.